# How to write a python package

Tags: python

I am trying to refactor my code (a bunch of core modules and some apps living in a common directory).
I want to get this structure

```
Root
   __init__.py
   Core
       __init__.py
       a.py
       b.py
       c.py
   AppOne
       __init__.py
       AppOne.py
   AppTwo
       __init__.py
       AppTwo.py
   AppThree
       __init__.py
       AppThree.py
```

where `AppOne.py`, `AppTwo.py` and `AppThree.py` imports the modules `a`, `b` and `c` in the `Core` package.

I don't understand how to write the `__init__.py` files and the import statements. I have read
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html and http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html. I got errors like "Attempted relative import in non-package" or "Invalid Sintaxis"

Comment: you can leave them (the `__init__.py`) empty and it will work.  you only need to put something there if you have particular special requirements (ie want to hide things).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the directory of the python modules to sys path.

If you have something like this

```
Root
   here_using_my_module.py
   my_module
       __init__.py  --> leave it empty
       a.py
       b.py
       c.py
```

You need to add you module directory to sys_path

```
//here_using_your_module.py
import os, sys

abspath = lambda *p: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*p))

PROJECT_ROOT = abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

sys.path.insert(0,PROJECT_ROOT)

import a from my_module

a.do_something()
```

Comment: This is the point! Thank you very much. I had forgotten to update sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

Within AppOne.py:

```
import os
os.chdir("..")

from Core import a
```

alternatively, you may write in AppOne.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(-1,"..")

from Core import a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have that *exact* directory structure, you can use relative imports to import from the parent folder:

```
from ..Core import a
```